# SQL Server 2016 R Services download

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install a new instance of SQL Server 2016 and when I get to the part where I install Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R Server it is now asking for the CAB files.

The two URLs which the setup says contains the CAB files are no longer available

> Setup was unable to contact the download server. Provide the location of the Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R Server installation files and click “Next”. The installation files can be downloaded from:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2134897&lcid=1033
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2136942&lcid=1033

I have searched on the Internet for these CAB files but every website about R Services seems to point back to the same URLs - HELP!

Does anyone know where I can download the files, I think the file are called something like `SRO_3.5.x.x_1033.CAB` and `SRS_8.x.x.x_1033.CAB`. I need them for SQL Server 2016 SP3 and I think the last version was for SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU14.

BTW: moving to SQL Server 2017 or 2019 would mean retesting the production suite which is something that is not currently planned in so we need to stick with 2016 for a little longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the latest links from https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-ml-cab-downloads?view=sql-server-2016 is down because the CDN domain, `rserverdistribution.azureedge.net` simply [can't be resolved](https://dnschecker.org/#A/rserverdistribution.azureedge.net). Luckily, both the [Microsoft R Open](http://web.archive.org/web/20221003070739/https://rserverdistribution.azureedge.net/production/SRO/3.5.2.777/1bf5922a-88d2-4c5d-aa82-bf0c01644e53/SRO_3.5.2.777_1033.cab) and [Microsoft R Server](http://web.archive.org/web/20201113015433/https://rserverdistribution.azureedge.net/production/SRS/9.4.7.958/2b0d46ed-57a0-4950-b062-c30c4f3985b8/SRS_9.4.7.958_1033.cab) is archived by Wayback Machine.

Comment: Wow, that seems to have worked. Many thanks!